# Вызов функции из функции ООП для Гуру

Tags: socket.io, javascript

Есть такой класс с внутренними методами:

```
function UserSubscribes(){ 
    this.channels = [];
    this.statusSubscribe = false;

    this.GetChannels = function(){ 
        var arg = this.channels;
        var res = JSON.parse(
        $.ajax({
            url: "/getUserChannels",
            type: "post",
            async: false, 
        }).responseText);

        if (res) {
          this.statusSubscribe = res.status;
              if (res.hasOwnProperty('user_channels')) { 
                for (var i = 0; i < res.user_channels.length; i++) { 
                    this.channels.push(res.user_channels[i].hash_channel);
                } 
                this.user_channels_json = res.id_user;
            } 
    } 
        return this.channels; 
    },

    this.CreateSocketsAccept = function(eventNameListen){
        for (i in eventNameListen) {
            socket.on(eventNameListen[i], function (data) {  // слушает и принимает событие
                **this.PrepareToHTMLdata**(data);
            });
        }

        return this.dataJSON;
    },

    **this.PrepareToHTMLdata** = function(dataJSON){
        switch (dataJSON.nameChannel) {
           case 'questions':
              alert('good');
              break
        }
    }
}

var user_subsc = new UserSubscribes(); 
var user_channels_json = user_subsc.GetChannels();

if (user_subsc.statusSubscribe) {
    user_subsc.CreateSocketsAccept(user_channels_json);
}
```

Выдает ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SocketNamespace> has no method 'PrepareToHTMLdata' 
Почему-то ругается на **this.PrepareToHTMLdata**(data)

Answer (score 1):

поправьте на

```
this.CreateSocketsAccept = function(eventNameListen){
    var self=this; //запомним this
    for (var i in eventNameListen) { //var забыли
        socket.on(eventNameListen[i], function (data) {  // слушает и принимает событие
            self.PrepareToHTMLdata(data); //т.к в обработчике события контекст обычно события а не вызвавшей функции
        });
    }
    return this.dataJSON; //тут у меня сомнения в том что вернет то что вы ожидаете.
},
```

и это.... вы бы лучше через prototype делали. и ещё - запомните: **в js нет классов**

Comment: Большое спасибо. Взял на заметку